# Using Regexp-match* to pull data in between two tags

Tags: racket

I need to be able to pull data in between to different points

```
 "test test <p>important information</p> test test test <p>more important information</p>"
```

the result should be '("important" "information" "more" "important" "information")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(define text "test test <p>important information</p> test test test <p>more important information</p>")
(append-map string-split
              (regexp-match* #px"<p>([a-z ]+)</p>" text #:match-select cadr))
```

Result is:
'("important" "information" "more" "important" "information")

Comment: One little thing to simplify: since you're flattening only one-level-down, you can use `(append-map ...)` instead of `(flatten (map ...))`

Answer (score 0):

Following works:

```
(define  str "test test <p>important information</p> test test test <p>more important information</p>")
(set! str (string-replace str "<p>" "|"))
(set! str (string-replace str "</p>" "|"))
(string-split 
 (string-join
  (for/list ((s (string-split str "|"))
             (i (in-naturals)) #:when (odd? i))
    s)))
```

Output:

```
'("important" "information" "more" "important" "information")
```

Comment: The conversion to use `|` pipes makes this way too brittle. For example if a If a `|` exists anywhere in the text originally this will do the wrong thing. Also if there is an unclosed `<p>` tag then everywhere after that it will include exactly the text that it shouldn't include. Those are just the first two things that came into my head.